# how to merge data from several tables in a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I want to create an overview monthly report for all the data in the worksheet. So for June, I'll see the sum of expenses, and sum of revenue, each existing in different tables.

| Expense | Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| expense 1 | 22/06/2022 | 100 |
| expense 2 | 25/06/2022 | 120 |
| expense 3 | 07/07/2022 | 60 |

| Revenue | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Salary | 11/06/2022 | 150 |
| Interest | 01/07/2022 | 20 |

Desired result

| Month | Expenses | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06-2022 | 220 | 150 |
| 07-2022 | 60 | 20 |

(I have a helper column month which converts date to a string month in the `m-yyyy` format)

I added all the tables to a data model, and created a pivot table from the data model. My problem, is that even though each table has the hidden "month" field, e.g. `06-2022`, for a "row" I have to select a month field from a specific table, and then other table does not break down for that month. And if I select both `month` fields for the pivottable row, I just get nested data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to solve it, but I am not sure my answer is ideal, so I'll accept other answers.

I used Power Query. I created queries from each of the source tables, removing most of the columns, and keeping only date and price. I renamed the price column "revenue" for both source tables, and I multiplied the price (now renamed revenue) of the expenses table by `-1`, since its function is to decrease revenue.

I then joined the two queries into a new query, removed the "day" part of the date by using the "begining of month transformation on the new query". Then I grouped all the rows by date, using the sum function on the revenue column. I saved the new query.

Then I created a relationships between the month of the query, and the month field of the `expense` table. I did the same for `income` table.

Finally, I was able to create a pivot table from the data model, with the month of the month query as rows, sum of expense price column, sum of income amount column, and sum of (but it's only one value anyway) month's query revenue column.

This works, but is slow, needs manual refreshing, and causes "foreign data" alerts in excel.